# How to setup /home over software RAID under Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have 3 hds, one of 500G which I installed Ubuntu 10.10 on, and two of 1TB each which I'd like build a RAID 0 volume on. My question are:

1) What are the pros and cons of using my motherboard RAID or Linux Software RAID?

2) How do I safely mount /home on that RAID volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux software RAID is pretty good.  If you have a high-end motherboard the hardware RAID me be faster, but the software RAID is going to be a lot more flexible, and you'll have all the tools for configuring it at your fingertips without having to boot into BIOS.

See the `mdadm` man page and the various documentation [here](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Linux_Raid).

> How do I safely mount /home on that RAID volume?

I'm not sure what you're asking here...mounting a RAID device is just like mounting any other device; you put an entry in your `/etc/fstab` file and the system will mount it automatically when it boots.  RAID devices are typically named `/dev/md0`, `/dev/md1`, and so forth, so your `fstab` might have an entry like this:

```
/dev/md0         /home            ext4    defaults              0       1
```

Comment: by "safely mount" I meant: how do I setup fstab (answered) and how do I safely move /home from non-raid disk to the raid disk?

Comment: Actually, I just discovered RAID support in Ubuntu's Disk Utility. Great tool. Just do "File" > "Create" > "RAID array...".

Comment: Moving /home:
http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 0):

High-end motherboards, as mentioned by larsks, should not be taken to mean motherboards that have "fakeRAID" support.  If you have one of those then you will have a much better time using Linux soft raid, unless you want to dual boot another OS on the same drive array.

Read up on [Ubuntu FakeRaid support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) if you fall into this category and want to pursue it.